# Agradecería saber cómo conseguir el directorio raíz de un proyecto firebase

Tags: firebase, react-native, firestore

### Hola!

**Recientemente he realizado un proyecto en React Native con Firebase, Node.js y Express.js.**

**El problema que deseo resolver es la posibilidad de poder "clonar" el proyecto en otro PC sin la necesidad de modificar manualmente el directorio del archivo `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` para no necesitar modificarlo para cada archivo, si no, que lo reconozca automáticamente.**

**El directorio específico de la ruta del proyecto lo conozco y es igual para todos. Lo que deseo es poder conseguir el directorio del PC donde se aloja el proyecto y evitar que la persona que desee clonar este proyecto deba tener que modificar esto a mano, evitándo que toque el `firebase.json`.**

**Esto es posible o existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo?**

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/<disco>/<name_pc>/<carpeta>/<root_proyecto>/<server>/firebase.json"
```

**Gracias!**